# Updating numpy array datastructure in Python

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, data-structures

I am having some trouble updating a data structure, and can't figure out why.

I have this data structure:

```
USER_EVENT_PAIR_NUMPY_DATA_TYPE = numpy.dtype([('user_id', numpy.int64, 1), ('dated_id', numpy.int64, 1),
                                          ('preference_value', numpy.float64, 1),
                                          ('weighted_preference_value', numpy.float64, 1),
                                          ('date_type', numpy.int8, 1),
                                          ('user_rating', numpy.int8, 1),
                                          ('pair_met_at_event_round_num', numpy.int16, 1),
                                          ('match_type', numpy.int8, 1)])
```

I create an array of them:

```
arr = numpy.empty([0,1],dtype=USER_EVENT_PAIR_NUMPY_DATA_TYPE)
```

And I periodically add rows to it:

```
row = numpy.array([(dater1.get_user_key,    #User1ID
                            dater2.get_user_key,    #User2ID
                            Dater1PreferenceVal,    #Initial preference value
                            0.0,                    #Weighted preference value
                            DateType,               # Date type
                            0,                      # User rating
                            -1,                     # Pair met at event round
                            0)],                    # Match type
                          dtype=USER_EVENT_PAIR_NUMPY_DATA_TYPE)

eupm = numpy.row_stack((eupm, row))
```

Then, later, I want to modify a value for a particular user pair (a combination of user_id and dated_id). However, when I do this, it is not changing the value in the array. If I print the value in the array before and after this set statement, it is the same. It is successfully reading the existing value from the array. What am I missing?

```
eupm[(eupm[:]['user_id'] == user1.get_user_key) & (eupm[:]['dated_id'] == user2.get_user_key)][0][2] = PreferenceVal
```

Thank you!

Comment: can you provide code also may be problem in your code?

Comment: The code is there, but it is hard to read, and hard to cut-n-paste.

Answer (score 0):

(first look)

If you are happy with `eupm` after the `row_stack` then that part of the code isn't the problem.  You aren't showing us the crucial part - how you attempt to change the values.

> Then, later, I want to modify a value for a particular user pair (a combination of user_id and dated_id). However, when I do this, it is not changing the value in the array.

This code is missing.

Are you, by any chance trying to modify two fields at once, e.g.

```
eupm[['user_id','dated_id']][row_select] = ('new','value')
```

Indexing multiple fields is not fully developed.  You can read the values, but you can't modify them.  You have to perform changes one field at a time, or change the whole record.

Your code is incomplete, so I am just making an educated guess.

===================================

(2nd detailed look)

Your `row` definition contains references to unknown values.  So I had to plug in my own values to do a cut-n-paste.  That is bad form.  If you want make it easy to replicate your results.

In your test, the `[:]` is superfluous:

```
In [163]: eupm[:]['user_id']
Out[163]: array([[123]], dtype=int64)
```

`eupm['user_id']` is sufficient.

Now that I'm actually trying to replicate your results, I see that the last expression is actually the assignment, not a test.  A long expression like that is hard to read.

```
eupm[(eupm[:]['user_id'] == user1.get_user_key) & (eupm[:]['dated_id'] == user2.get_user_key)][0][2] = PreferenceVal
```

Here's something which is, hopefully more readable:

```
In [167]: mask=(eupm['user_id'] == 123) & (eupm['dated_id'] == 123)

In [168]: mask
Out[168]: array([[ True]], dtype=bool)

In [169]: eupm[mask]
Out[169]: 
array([(123L, 123L, 123.0, 0.0, 123, 0, -1, 0)], 
      dtype=[('user_id', '<i8'), ('dated_id', '<i8'), ('preference_value', '<f8'), ('weighted_preference_value', '<f8'), ('date_type', 'i1'), ('user_rating', 'i1'), ('pair_met_at_event_round_num', '<i2'), ('match_type', 'i1')])
```

So I found an element(s) that satisfies the 2 id conditions.

```
In [170]: eupm[mask][0]
Out[170]: (123L, 123L, 123.0, 0.0, 123, 0, -1, 0)
```

So this pulled out the first record

```
In [171]: eupm[mask][0][2]
Out[171]: 123.0
```

And the 3rd field.  I would have use the field name:

```
In [174]: eupm[mask][0]['preference_value']
Out[174]: 123.0
```

Finally you try an assignment:

```
In [172]: eupm[mask][0][2]=1000
```

And no change:

```
In [173]: eupm
Out[173]: 
array([[(123L, 123L, 123.0, 0.0, 123, 0, -1, 0)]], 
      dtype=[('user_id', '<i8'), ('dated_id', '<i8'), ('preference_value', '<f8'), ('weighted_preference_value', '<f8'), ('date_type', 'i1'), ('user_rating', 'i1'), ('pair_met_at_event_round_num', '<i2'), ('match_type', 'i1')])
```

The issue here is that `eupm[mask]` is a copy, not a view.

And example of using a view is:

```
In [176]: eupm[:1][0]['preference_value']=1000

In [177]: eupm
Out[177]: 
array([[(123L, 123L, 1000.0, 0.0, 123, 0, -1, 0)]], ...)
```

Any time you index an array with a boolean mask you get a copy, and you have to be very careful about using a second index.

```
arr[mask][0] = ...   # does not work
```

What I think you need to do is get the row number, and index with that:

```
In [180]: idx=numpy.where(mask)    
In [181]: idx
Out[181]: (array([0]), array([0]))  # eupm is (1,1) (2d)
In [182]: idx=idx[0][0]  # 2d makes selecting the index more complicated
```

Correct indexing:

```
In [187]: eupm[idx,0]['preference_value']=2000
```

Do you really need to initial `arr` to (0,1) shape?  2d?  Your complex `dtype` is already providing the pseudo-2d structure.

I realize my answer is long and somewhat rambling, but that's the nature of real life debugging.

====================

You can also index by field first (this creates a view):

```
eupm['preference_value'][mask]=3000
```

But you still can't apply an extra `[0]` to this.